# Animate meteor traveling from top to bottom in Swift 3

Tags: swift, animation, swift3, uiimageview, uiimage

I want an image of a red circle to move from the top of the screen to the bottom, as though it were a meteor traveling across the screen. It does move, but it moves in a millisecond with no animation. How do I make it move smoothly like a meteor with a tail?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let meteorImage = UIImageView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.meteorImage.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.meteorImage.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
        self.meteorImage.isHidden = false
        self.meteorImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "success")
        view.addSubview(self.meteorImage)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let totalHeight = Int(view.frame.height)
        var currentHeight = 0

        while currentHeight < totalHeight {
            self.meteorImage.backgroundColor = .clear
            self.meteorImage.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: currentHeight, width: 50, height: 50)
            self.meteorImage.isHidden = false
            self.meteorImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "success")
            view.addSubview(self.meteorImage)
            currentHeight += 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using UIKit Dynamics.

Answer (score 1):

Animations have to be done with an animate call.

This is a simple way to do an animation.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: { 
   // Apply Changes to frame.
})
```

Consider also: instead of doing the while loop simply set the final location of the meteor's frame and set the duration to the amount of time you want it to take.

```
let newFrame= CGRect(x: 50, 
                     y: currentHeight, 
                     width: 50, 
                     height: 50)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, animations: { 
   // Apply Changes to frame.
   self.meteorImage.frame = newFrame
})
```

If you want to make your animation more complicated you can look into keyframe animations on a UIView.